# How to check button is enabled or disabled in selenium

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, selenium, automated-tests, mstest

I am trying to check whether the button is enabled or disabled. I am doing the following

```
Assert.IsTrue(Browser.IsEditable(button))
```

but it gives me error that expression does not produce a value. Any one know how to achieve this. Currently I am using VS2010 MStest in vb.net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you assert for the presence of the "disabled" property of the button?

```
Assert.IsTrue(selenium.IsElementPresent("css=input[disabled]"));
```